# How to install application on real android phone

Tags: debugging, android

I have created one SMSapplication and i need to test it on my android phone.
i have already tried other options like enable USB debugging in manifest file and also device
but it's not working.. any other option. pls help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install USB drivers on system, you can use following link for refence of steps and driver links:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

If you still facing issue, see following article.

http://appsandroid.in/connect-android-phone-to-pc-laptop-computer-mac-vi-usb-cablea

Once connected to system, To install application on device see, link:
http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/install-apk-files-on-android/#.TzZn2chG2nA

Answer (score 2):

first of all, you need to get the driver of your phone.
then, you need to set your phone on debugging mode as follows:
settings > applications > development > check the debugging mode box.
if you are using eclipse then, go to run > debug configurations > testing >under the target tap make it manual to be able to choose your device ....

if still not working, connect your phone to the pc as a mass storage and copy the .apk file to it and then install it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to package the application to an `.apk` file.

About that, the best solution is probably to take a look at the developpers' documentation -- the [**Preparing for release**](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html) section should be kind of a good start.

Then, upload that .apk to your phone *(using the USB-mass storage feature, for example ; or using FTP/samba applications)* like you would do for any other file.

And, finally, open that `.apk` using some file-explorer application ; which will propose you to install it.

Note that it is also possible to debug on a real device *(instead of using the emulator)* ; [**Using Hardware Devices**](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) should be what you'll want to read, about that.